# sql exceptions when reading, updating and writing

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

What are the sql exceptions will thrown by using the following function:

1. Read
2. Update
3. Write

Comment: I'm not familiar with those functions. Could you define which class and methods you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, you need to make your question more specific.. And try to make the title clearer too :)

Comment: i meant the functions that are personally created for the data entering, updating, and existing data reading.. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SqlException` class exposes an `Errors` property which is an `SqlErrorCollection` containing instances of the `SqlError` class. Each `SqlError` instance represents a particular Error message that was returned from SQL server.

By the same token, the `OleDbException` class enables you to get at each `OleDbError` returned from the OleDb datasource.

So, in other words, you will not see different CLI exceptions being raised for each kind of SQL operation - you will only receive an `SqlException`. The onus is on you to examine the errors therein.